# Map vs Unordered_map-- Multithreading

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, dictionary, unordered-map

I have the following requirements:

I need a datastructure with key,value pairs(keys are integers if that helps).

I need the below operations:-

1. Iteration(most used)
2. Insertion (2nd most used)
3. Searching by key and deletion(least)

I plan to use multiple locks over the structure for concurrent access. 
What is the ideal data structure to use?

Map or an unordered map?

I think unordered map makes sense, because i can insert in O(1), delete in O(1). But i am not sure of the iteration. How bad is the performance when compared to map?

Also, i plan to use multiple locks on blocks instead of the whole structure. Any good implementation example of this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The speed of iterator incrementing is `O(1)` for both containers, although you might get somewhat better cache locality from `std::unordered_map`.

Apart from the slower `O(log N)` find/insert/erase  functionality of `std::map`, one other difference is that `std::map` provides **bidirectional** iterators, whereas the faster (amortized `O(1)` element access) `std::unordered_map` only provides **forward** iterators.

The excellent book [**C++ Concurrency in Action: Practical Multithreading**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1933988770) by Anthony Williams provides a code example of a multithreaded `unordered_map` with a lock per entry. This book is highly recommended if you are doing serious multithreaded coding.

Answer (score 0):

Iteration is not a problem in an `unordered_map`. It is a little less efficient than a vector, but not largely so.

As always, you will need to benchmark for YOUR use-cases, and compare with other container types if it's a critical part of your code.

Not sure what you mean by "multiple locks on blocks instead of the whole structure" - any container updates will need to be locked for the whole container...

Comment: What i mean is to divide the hash structure internally into number of blocks, and apply locks only on those bocks of the container not on the complete container. Say a structure has 10000 buckets, i can internally break it down into 100 blocks of 100 buckets and lock only those blocks

Comment: So, you are not planning to use the `std::unordered_map` - if that's not the case, how are we supposed to be able to tell you how efficient or not, it is?

Comment: I am sorry if i am being naive, but i am not clear on why it is not possible. Is it not possible to have a wrapper class around the unordered_map, where i can make sure specific elements[mapped to specific blocks] are accessed only through specific locks?

Comment: I don't think you can do that without intrusive access into the class itself. And a wrapper can't really do that.You need to know whether has 47112121 and 139198 end up in the same bucket or not, and the only way to know that is to know the actual implementation.

Comment: Oh, i was being naive :P. I thought i could define my own hash function and get that information. I will research more else come up with my own hash implementation. Thanks for the info anyways

Comment: It shouldn't really matter THAT much - since inserting and removing elements is pretty quick, you shouldn't need to lock for very long.

Comment: Just for whomever else may read this: [`std::unordered_map::bucket()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/bucket) could be used to get the bucket number, but then there's probaby no reason to divide the work based on bucket ranges rather than just using `hash(key) % 100` as an index into the locks.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply use an existing `concurrent_unordered_map` which you can find in both [TBB](http://threadingbuildingblocks.org/docs/help/reference/containers_overview/concurrent_unordered_map_cls.htm) and [Concrt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh750089.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about trying a `std::deque` The reasoning being as follows:

1. Iteration is fast - data should be more or less packed close (unlike lists)
2. Insertion (at either end) should be quick - data in a deque is never resized
3. Iteration and deletion slow (but uncommon usecase).

If the last two cases are common, a `std::list` may be used. Also consider testing a std::vector` since it is more cache efficient.

Iteration in an `unordered_map` may be slow due to iterating over a large number of unused elements in the hashtable. Insertions will be quich until collision levels become intolerable at which point the whole data structure will need to laid out again.

`map`s have relatively fast iteration except that data elements may be far apart. Insertion can be slow due to the re-balancing of the red-black trees that this requires.

The main usecase for unordered_maps is for fast lookup (O1). normal map have fastish lookup (O log n) but much better iteration performance.

Comment: _"Iteration in an unordered_map may be slow due to iterating over a large number of unused elements in the hashtable."_ quality implementations can easily avoid that, e.g. the buckets in GCC's unordered containers can store iterators into a singly-linked list of elements: when iterating, the buckets themselves aren't inspected.

Answer (score 0):

If you have hard real-time requirements, I would recommend map over unordered_map. std::map has guaranteed performance 100% of the time, but the std::unordered_map may do a rehash and completely ruin real-time performance in some critical corner case. In general, I prefer red-black trees (std::map) over hashtables (std::unordered_map) if I need absolute guarantees on worst-case performance.